# How to set the default url for webview app in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, url

I am pretty new to Xcode and app development.

I have a platform that has a homepage with a login form and the designated Login/Join page(s).

My webview app is built to open the main URL where the homepage is located, e.g domain.com.
How can I set up to show the login page when the app is open instead of the main URL, e.g. domain.com/signin

I assume I should be able to set it up in the Xcode. Also, if this change is made in the Xcode will it sync with my App Dev Account?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a WKWebView you can load a new page as so:

```
var webView = WKWebView()

if let loginUrl = URL(string: "domain.com/signin") {
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

A couple resources for you to learn more about WebKit:

https://medium.com/swift-productions/create-a-web-view-xcode-12-swift-5-3-9806d41cc9b

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/4/2/creating-a-simple-browser-with-wkwebview

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sam! Actually, I am not using WKWebView.